# How do skype extensions for browsers actually work?

Tags: firefox-addon, skype, browser-addons

We have plans of developing a web application that will have to communicate with our locally running application. One of the possible options is using browser extensions. I was looking into how Skype add-ons to browsers communicate with Skype client.  In Firefox, Skype add-on inserts a piece of HTML when it encounters a phone number. 
Is this

```
<span skypeaction="...">
```

processed by a Skype extension which makes a call using Skype API? Do extensions for other browsers use Skype API or other communications mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a bit of research and here's what I found. When the user clicks on the Skype link injected by the extension, the extension creates a new Skype process and passes it the parameters specifying the action and the number. Custom protocol handler is not used.

Answer (score 0):

The Skype extension would use regular expressions to search for valid and visible phone numbers displayed on a webpage, and as you say it would wrap a span class around it.

The span class would be defined within the extension code, and would insert the skype icon along with a clickable link that launches the skype application.

You also see similar functionality from iTunes and IRC, they have links in the `irc://...` format.

Comment: For me, the Firefox extension changes phone numbers into Skype links only if Skype is already launched. I wonder what is the mechanism of communication between the extension and the Skype app - is it Skype API or ... ?

Comment: To prove, I did an experiment. I modified the registry entry for custom skype: protocol, specifying an invalid path to Skype app. After this, the normal Skype link on a webpage stopped working. But the link injected by Firefox extension remained working. Looks like the extension uses Skype API.